# No external crate `erc721`

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I am very new to rust so a lot of things are still not fully clear to me. I have two dependencies in my `cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
erc721 = "3.0.0"
soroban-sdk = "0.9.2"
```

And I'm importing them into my `lib.rs` like this:

```
#![no_std]
use soroban_sdk::{contract, contractimpl, symbol_short, vec, Env, Symbol, Vec};
use erc721;
```

Soroban sdk works well, but I have a problem to import erc721.
The error I get is:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `erc721`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use erc721;
  |     ^^^^^^ no external crate `erc721`
```

I tried to import it like this:
`use erc721::Erc721;`
And also tried something similar to `soroban_sdk` since I want to test the mint() function from erc721 crate. `use erc721::{ mint };` but it gives me the same error.

[erc721 crate](https://docs.rs/erc721/3.0.0/erc721/)

Answer (score 0):

`erc721` is a [cdylib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html) crate, which is defined in it's [Cargo.toml](https://docs.rs/crate/erc721/3.0.0/source/Cargo.toml) in `[lib]` section:

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
name = "erc721"
path = "lib.rs"
```

This means you cannot use it as a rust library, but rather you have to link to it as you would to a `C` library.

Comment: Ok so how do you see that it is a part of cdylib crate? In https://crates.io/crates/erc721 it says to use `cargo add erc721` script or add `erc721 = "3.0.0"` to cargo.toml file, but when I use `cargo add erc721` I get another error now: `Deprecated dependency sections are unsupported: dev_dependencies`
And how do I use it if I link it like you specified?

Comment: I would guess that you have to build it and link to it in a build script, but you should probably contact the author, since this seems to be a niche and not documented library.